# MySQL/DB Error: MAX JOIN SIZE

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can anyone suggest ways I can resolve this error:

> DB Error: The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check
>   your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the
>   SELECT is okay

My MySQL is from shared hosting.

Thanking you.

Comment: It's hard to give a specific answer without seeing your query and the sizes of your tables. But you may be able to alleviate it by joining subqueries.